# RSA- BIgInteger Issue

Tags: java

I want to use [RSA algorithm](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/78crypto/RSA.java.html), for encrypt and decrypt messages. Now, as RSA can encrypt and decrypt Big-integer (or Integer) value, I need the message as Big-integer value. Now, message can contain strings like "ABC 123". What can I do ? Any help or suggestion ?

Comment: "I need my message as Big-integer" - ???

Comment: Encryption algorithms encrypt strings of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, by using

```
byte[] b = message.getBytes()
BigInteger = new BigInteger (b)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your message is initially ascii, you can use something like:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger();
While(j < msg.length() ) {
  i += ((byte)msg.charAt(j) << (j*7));
}
```

For working code consult the actual JavaDocs. But basically you just want to turn your bytes or chars into a number, so the idea is you just concatenate the bits together.

Comment: Thanks gotafex. I find another way, posted below.